# How to create table from qry result that has date calculation in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, create-table

I want to create a table from qry result. The following qry runs OK:

```
create table x select 
date_format(TERMINATION_DT,'%Y-%m-%d') as Term_Date
, date_format(BIRTH_DT,'%Y-%m-%d') as DOB
from dashboard_04102014
where status = 'withdrawn';
```

There are some `termination_dt` values are empty `''`. the `where status = 'withdrawn'` filters out the empty values. However, when I tried to perform date calc with the following qry, I got an error message:

```
create table x select 
date_format(TERMINATION_DT,'%Y-%m-%d') as Term_Date
, round(datediff(date_format(TERMINATION_DT,'%Y-%m-%d'), date_format(BIRTH_DT,'%Y-%m-%d'))/365,0) as Age
from dashboard_04102014
where status = 'withdrawn';
```

Here is the error msg:

```
incorrect datetime value" '0000-00-00'
```

I am guessing that those empty `termination_dt` values were converted to `0000-00-00` that throws off the `datediff`? But those values are filtered out with the where clause in the first place.

Also, I can run the `select` part perfectly fine and it returns the results I want. But when I wanted to create a table from it, then I got the error message with the 2nd qry. Why I can create table with the 1st qry but not the 2nd?

Thanks!

ADD Original Table strip:

```
CREATE TABLE dashboard_04102014
   (`status` varchar(9), `termination_dt` int, `birth_dt` int);

INSERT INTO Table1
(`status`, `termination_dt`, `birth_dt`)
VALUES
('Active', 0, 19560329),
('Withdrawn', 20070208, 19690131),
('Withdrawn', 20090702, 19441219),
('Active', 0, 19520912),
('Withdrawn', 20130730, 19480404);
```

Comment: What is the actual data type defined on the `termination_dt` and `birth_dt`? Was they `date`, `datetime`, `timestamp` or something else?

Comment: Run a `select` on created table `x` and see if the records are in proper date format and values.

Comment: maybe it is overkill, but try to cast the value to date: `cast(date_format(termination_dt, '%Y-%m-%d') as date)`

Comment: @Ravinder - the original data type for `termination_dt` and `birth_dt` is `integer`, i.e. `20110101`, `20110201`, `20140401` etc. But there are many rows that don't have value for `termination_dt`. So after converting to date, the new value is `0000-00-00`. I dont know if that throws off the calculation.

Comment: `don't have value` means what? Are they empty `''` or `NULL`?

Comment: they are empty, however, when I ran the first qry (without `datediff`), these empty values are converted to `0000-00-00`. I forgot to mention that there is `where` clause in the qry that filter out the empty `termination_dt`.

Comment: @Ravinder - I edited my original post to make it more clear.

Comment: @PerriMa: You mean, you want to omit `empty` or `null` dates from selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not selecting `NULL` or `empty` entries from the date columns, then

```
drop table if exists x;

create table x 
select 
  cast( date_format( BIRTH_DT,'%Y-%m-%d' ) as date ) as BIRTH_DT
  , cast( date_format( TERMINATION_DT,'%Y-%m-%d' ) as date ) as Term_Date
  , cast( round( datediff( date_format( TERMINATION_DT, '%Y-%m-%d' ), 
                     date_format( BIRTH_DT, '%Y-%m-%d' ) 
                 ) / 365, 0 ) as decimal( 6, 2 ) ) as Age
from dashboard_04102014
where 
      status = 'withdrawn'
      -- un comment following line if required
      -- AND ( BIRTH_DT is not null and BIRTH_DT = '' and BIRTH != 0 )
  and ( TERMINATION_DT is not null 
        and TERMINATION_DT != '' 
        and TERMINATION_DT != 0 )
;
```

**Result**:

```
desc x;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BIRTH_DT  | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Term_Date | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Age       | decimal(6,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

select * from x;
+------------+------------+-------+
| BIRTH_DT   | Term_Date  | Age   |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 1992-07-31 | 2050-07-31 | 58.00 |
| 1971-02-24 | 2029-02-24 | 58.00 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

**Demo 1** @ [***MySQL 5.5.32 Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0a98/1)
**Demo 2** @ [***MySQL 5.5.32 Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6812/6)

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I tried your qry, and I still got the same error message `Incorrect datetime value:'0000-00-00'. But it looks like you got the results just fine. To confirm, BIRTH_DT has no null or ''.

Comment: Check my updated answer with new [*My SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6812/6)

Comment: Hi Ravinder, IT WORKED!!! So the `and ( TERMINATION_DT is not null    and TERMINATION_DT != '' and TERMINATION_DT != 0 )` did the trick. I also removed the `cast` and it worked fine. Thanks again for your time helping me!!!

Comment: @PerriMa: If you remove `cast`, then the resulting column would be `varchar`.

Comment: Hi Ravinder.. I see... but the calculated results from `datediff` is accurate though. So it is seeing the `termination_dt` and `birth_dt` as date, even the `desc` shows them as `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should mention the `datetime` datatype

> Illegal DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', or 00000000000000).

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html***

if your mention `datetime` means you should mention like:

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: i edited the original post to make it more clear. when you say "I should mention date time data type", you mean in the post or in the create table stmt?